# Perforce equivalent command to svn export

Tags: svn, perforce

I am trying to modify my build script to work with a new project that is based in perforce. The script creates a tag and then wants to check out the tag into a temp directory. In subversion I would use in the `svn export` command. In git I would `git archive | tar -x`. Is there an equivalent command in `p4`? Or am I required to set up a temporary client space, sync, build, and then delete the client space?

Answer (score 2):

Sven Erik Knop wrote submitted a script to he Perforce Public depot that uses p4 print (via P4Python) to create a zip file containing a file tree. You can find it here:

https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/guest/sven_erik_knop/P4Pythonlib/scripts/PrintZip.py

Update: Swarm has a download button that will zip up a directory in a similar manner.

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I get a chance.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

creating and sync'ing a client is what I've always done. I don't know why you'd need to build the client, though; just create it, sync it, tar the client-side files, sync it to #0 to clean up the mess, and delete the client. That seems like a straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could use `p4 print` to obtain file content without using a workspace.  However I think you'll find that using a workspace is easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a  modern git with perforce included:

```
git p4 clone //path/to/depot/... target_folder && rm -rf target_folder/.git
```

The rm part is optional, of course, to remove the .git if you don't want it.